# Why are my WebDriver wait methods not consitently clicking on the button?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Why are my WebDriver wait methods not consitently clicking on the button?

For example out of every 100 tests 7 will fail saying the locator is not visible, but when looking at the screenshot the button is clearly there!

```
<input class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle buynow" aria-expanded="false" value="Buy Now" type="submit"/>
```

I have tried waits, normal clicks, loop and JS clicks etc nothink consistently clicks on the button.

```
    public void waitAndClickElement(WebElement element) throws InterruptedException {
    boolean clicked = false;
    int attempts = 0;
    while (!clicked && attempts < 1000) {
        try {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)).click();
            System.out.println("Successfully clicked on the WebElement: " + element.toString());
            clicked = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to wait and click on WebElement" + element + ", Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            Assert.fail("Method failed: waitAndClickElement");
            //Assert.fail("Unable to wait and click on the WebElement, using locator: " + element.toString());
        }
        attempts++;
    }

}

public void clickOnBuyNowButton() throws InterruptedException {
    WebElement buyNowButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/input"));
    WaitUntilWebElementIsVisible(buyNowButton);
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(buyNowButton).doubleClick().build().perform();
}
```

Any ideas? am i doing soemthing wrong?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try following; in here I'm first waiting for an element to be clickable and then once it becomes clickable I'm moving to it and then throwing my click:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(yourElement));

Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToEelment(yourElement).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: @kushal.even that dosnt work :/ its as if even though a timeout of lets say 15seconds has been set, it dosnt then keep trying to click the element

Comment: What happens when 20 seconds have passed?

Comment: @kushal.an exception would be thrown for example unable to click on element or locator is not visible, but i have captured screenshots and the button is there

Comment: Selenium works solely with DOM, so if an element should be present there for selenium to interact; anyways have you tries JavascriptExecutor? and actions class?

Comment: yeh im afraid i have :/

Comment: I'd like you to run my code first and then print stacktrace